# Free-floating magical effects and planetary rotation

Tags: system-agnostic, magic, teleportation

Many magic systems allow the creation of magical effects such as teleportation portals which are not anchored to a physical object, but rather conjured floating in the air.  However, many settings are worlds just like our own, set on spinning, orbiting planets.  Shouldn't these unattached portals and things remain in place while the planet spins away - or shouldn't they collide, teleporting a narrow tunnel right through the earth and leaving a curved hole?  Is "Ho ho, MAGIC!" really a sufficient explanation for how a caster can calculate for the curve of the Earth, its rotation on a tilted axis, its orbit around the sun, and the expansion of the universe?

Isn't it just too much of a handwave?  **How do games justify unanchored magical effects ignoring celestial mechanics?**

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately this question is not a good fit as it stands, as it seems to be encouraging discussion and would be more suited to a forum based website.

Comment: I see. The majority of questions asked on here seemed to be the sort of discussions I'd felt this was in the vein of. I apologize for the misunderstanding. What sort of adjustments should be made to this question to keep it in the spirit of discussion the other questions of the site are otherwise geared toward?

Comment: Questions on StackExchange should be *answerable*, a right answer should be able to say why it's right.  This question seems very opinion-based as written, in that there may be multiple right answers or no way to objectively identify an answer as "right" or "wrong".  Not every question adheres to it perfectly, but with experience with the site you get a better feel for which questions have room for subjectivity and which are better asked in a discussion forum (or, with 20 rep, in our chat room).  Even if this question is closed, we're glad you're here and hope you stick around!

Comment: as an aside, this question might be a better fit for the World Building stack exchange site, but I'm not certain as I've never used it.

Comment: Despite knowing it will attract all the downvotes, I might as well try to answer the actual question I feel like is lying underneath this one.

Comment: Are things here really so...contemptuous toward newcomers and unstructured questions that you feel more folks would put the time into showing up just to downvote rather than chime in toward an answer? If that's the case, that last thing I'd want is for anyone to have their earned reputations shot to hell over trying to be helpful and constructive with this.

Comment: No to new users, no, but yes to unstructured questions. (Though "contemptuous" is not the right word either, since that implies it's a matter of emotion.) We just don't accept unstructured questions at all. In fact, we got an unstructured question two days ago from a very active and high-rep user, and promptly closed it too. As for downvoting people who answer when we know they know the question doesn't fit here, that's done because it's a bad habit that needs to be discouraged. (But won't shoot their rep to hell. It takes *many* downvotes to make even a small dent.)

Comment: My answer will probably be downvoted, because it's considered bad form to answer a question that doesn't fit the format.  I brush up against that rule when it comes to questions that I feel are likely to be improved, or questions that are very borderline.  I feel like this question has an actual, answerable *question* hidden underneath the discussion prompt written above;  something like "How do I justify unanchored magic not flying off the planet?"  I tried to answer the question I think you meant rather than the question you wrote;  downvotes are very tiny marks on my solid rep, no worries.

Comment: My previous comment was a little sarcastic, I realize it might not be readily identified as such.  I threw it out there because a lot of regular users around here know just how often I bash into particular conventions (game recommendations is a topic I've railed against the majority opinion on in the past), and it was a nod to them, a sort of permission or acknowledgement so they know it won't hurt my feelings if I draw the downvotes.  Please don't be concerned for my reputation - it was a bit of an in-joke, and I didn't consider how it would look to someone not in on the joke.

Comment: The dreaded triple-comment is also frowned upon, but I wanted to make sure you knew, Eiketsu:  If the question is closed, that isn't the end.  If you can edit the question to make it a question instead of a "discussion prompt", if you follow, it stands a good likelihood of being reopened.  There's no time limit to do so, either;  take your time, decide what you're trying to ask, and if you think it fits the site, make the edit.  If not, no harm done.  We still want you to feel welcome to ask and answer questions here;  the format can be a "learning curve" but don't let it be an obstacle. ^_^

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the clarification AND the answer to that (very significant) side of the question. :)

Comment: @Eiketsu Like I said, I've considered this question fairly often, although never with portals as the primary object.  I hope my edit gets to the heart of what you were asking - if you feel it doesn't, it can be reverted by clicking on the "edited [time] ago" above my name at the bottom of the question and you can give it a go yourself.

Comment: I think it's a good question. You could put it on WorldBuilding.StackExchange, but it would need to be in terms of considering how magic would work in a world with such spells but that wanted to be fairly consistent with physics.

Comment: In keeping with the whole "better understanding of things around here", is it par for the course for people to just check in on Questions, downvote their contents, then move on without any explanation or constructive contribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lacking a system tag to guide an answer to a specific system, I'll list a few ways I've seen this handled, both in canon and by GM decisions.

- **Many fantasy worlds aren't hurtling through space.**  Many Dungeons-and-Dragons campaign settings either have edges (nearly-flat worlds) or are the centers of their universe (the sun revolves around the Earth).  Exalted's Creation is a literally-flat world, where instead of the curvature of the Earth causing a maximum sight-distance, the Loom of Fate that runs the world like a giant supercomputer running a simulation actually enforces a "draw distance" (if you're familiar with the computer term).
- **Many magic systems consider the planet to be a magical entity.**  Shadowrun 5e calls this the Gaiasphere, the area where the Earth and all its lifeforms produce life energy and thus enable magic use.  As magi travel into space, their magical abilities can quit working, become harder to use (magic in Shadowrun damages its user in an effect called Drain), or have reduced effect.  In this setting, your magical portal or *rope trick* spell that doesn't appear to be anchored to an object is still anchored to *its position relative to the planet the spell was cast on*, even if it doesn't physically touch the planet.
- **Magic is governed by its own laws.**  It often does things that seem impossible.  Most magical portals have no mass and do not interact with gases surrounding them.  Does it really seem like the spell couldn't be set in a super-low orbit?  *Why* shouldn't it fly at unimaginable speeds just to keep up with the surroundings where it was cast?  In the Mage setting (inside White Wolf's "World of Darkness"), magic is a matter of imposing your beliefs over the communal beliefs of the common people around you.  This means all magic in that setting is *relative*.  As long as the *observers* continue to believe your portal remains floating in the skies over Long Island, it will continue to do so.  Physical locations are irrelevant (especially when Correspondence magic - that is, the magic that actually deals with teleportation and such - is in play).
- **Rule Zero, and common sense.**  You don't have to calculate the curvature of the Earth vs. an elliptical orbit vs. leeward rotation on a tilted axis every time you throw a ball in your backyard, do you?  Of course not.  Things that happen on a planet typically ignore the planet's intergalactic travel.  Sure, some tides and weather patterns pay attention, and things like comets and solar flares get noticed, but nearly everything else is simply unimportant.  Taking those things into account for a simple teleportation spell should be a huge and involving *exception*, not the basic way things work.  (For an example of this at work, see the movie *Jumper*.  The movie's pretty hit-or-miss, but the climax scene is pretty awesome for someone who's actually considered the juxtaposition of magic and planetary rotation.)

[Side note for spells that aren't of unlimited range and duration, since you mentioned other magical effects that float unsupported:  **The magic-user is a magical anchor point.**  Spells like the various *hands* made of force or *spiritual weapons* that fight on their own typically wink out of existence if they go beyond a certain range of the caster.  Perhaps they use the caster's own aura as a point of reference to stop the planetary-scale movements from causing them to go flying off/through the planet?  Just a thought.]

Comment: Thank you. I enjoy the multiple perspectives you answered this from, especially citing a wide variety of game systems I all but grew up on, and stand as the various roots this question grew from. I especially like the idea of applying Mage.

Also, you've given me even more motivation to check out the new Shadowrun. I've been curious as to whether or not it's as convoluted as the previous editions, and your reference to it adds another facet to all of this. Consider this the vote up I can't quite give you yet. :)

Comment: You're welcome.  I still hold out hope you'll find a way to improve the question and get it reopened;  I'd love to see competing viewpoints on the topic.  I'd never considered things like portals that aren't anchored (Mage and DnD both like to anchor theirs), but Immovable Rods in DnD are a common source of frustration to people with any knowledge of celestial mechanics.  I once had an Earth-centric setting where Immovable Rods were becoming the answer to everything to the point I rules that discovered rods had a 10% chance to not remain relative to rotation... :D

Comment: I'd like to see it reopened and encouraging different viewpoints and discussion as well, but I'm just not seeing how to reword it toward that end. I like the responses you provided; they're definitely along the lines of what I was hoping for. I suppose that'll be the best I can get with my flop of a first question here. Oh, well. Thanks again for your input and assistance. Better luck next time, eh?

Comment: @Gatherer818 I *would* urge you to delete this answer until the question has been improved. As you can see, giving an answer to a closed question reduces the willingness of the querent to improve it. If you want to delete it, just flag it for moderator attention and we'll take care of it.

Comment: @Eiketsu "Discussion" is the taboo word here. We work best on *answerable* questions, where each answer addresses the question. Perhaps this question would be much better asked on worldbulding.se?

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton Eiketsu has stated a few times that he's not sure how to improve the question.  I myself have tried to put into words what I feel the real question is.  I was hoping the answer would help, give us a point to work backward from and improve the question.  It seems obvious what he's trying to ask...  maybe I'll give it a shot anyway.

Comment: Isn't this extensively *discussed* question just another example of what I'm being told I did wrong with this one?
http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10421/how-do-i-create-a-sense-of-mystery-about-magic?

Comment: @Eiketsu I understand your frustration.  Notice how the question you linked has a lot of phrases like "How do I..." and "What should I do if I want *this*..."?  Your "question", as originally phrased, had no *answer*.  It was just a call to discussion, not a question.  You should have the reputation to ask questions on [the meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/) now;  feel free to ask there where you'll get more answers (I was the only one notified that you made this comment, others might not see it) from people who better understand the community.